# Pegar value script Confirm e passar para PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tem como fazer isso? Os dados do confirm de um `<script></script>` ir pra URL? Pra funcionar no PHP usando o `$_GET[""];`

Comment: Para o mesmo PHP atual ou para um AJAX ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim!

Você pode fazer de 2 formas, escolha a que mais se adapte ao que você quer:

**Redireciona para uma página PHP passando a Query String nome**

```
var nome = prompt("Informe seu nome");

window.location.href='arquivo.php?nome='+nome;
```

**Enviando via Ajax**

jQuery:

```
var nome = prompt("Informe seu nome");

$.ajax({
    url: 'arquivo.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {nome: nome},

    success: function(resposta){

        alert(resposta);
    }
});
```

Pegando os dados passado na URL:

```
<?php
echo 'O nome informado é '.$_GET['nome'];
?>
```

Comment: Com Ajax não deu não, não enviou a informação pa URL